# printing "please enter a number" each time I press enter with only alphabet input

Tags: c, scanf, buffer, enter

I want to prompt the user to "Please input a number" whenever the user presses the enter key.
First look the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    char b, c;
    int flag = 1;
    while (true) {
        flag = 0;

        if (scanf("%d", &a) == 1)
            break;
        scanf("%c", &b); // this is to clear the frontline characters gradually
        // such that number embedded in the input can be read
        // for e.g. aa4, abdk2jsdl etc
    }
    do {
        scanf("%c", &c); // this is to clear the '\n' buffer if number is the last input(4, as4,hdd7 etc)
        // and others if the input was a2ssdf

    } while (c != 10); // where the buffers will be ssdf and '\n' character

    printf("the number is:%d", a);
}
```

I was trying to create aninput system using only scanf and without using string. I know using strings will make it more easier. The input system is such that unless user input a number it will keep asking and simultaneously also clearing out all the buffers without using fflush, as it is not standard.

So everything was fine till here. But now I want to add an extra feature to tell the user "Please enter a number" if the user input something like aaaaa,dsfk with only alphabets. so, to be clear I will give an
example...

**input:** aaa             **output**: please enter a number.

**2nd input**: hz2         **2nd output**: You entered 2.

But what I'm capable of doing right now is..

**Output of above input "aaa"**: please enter a numberplease enter a numberplease enter a number

So Basically I want to print it only when user hit the enter key and only once
you got any idea? It's without using string.

Comment: Homework? Is using `scanf()` a requirement? Why not use a function which reads a single character, for example `getchar()`?

Comment: Why include the same header file twice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
int getnum() {
    int input;
    int num = 0;
    while(1) {
        if((input = getchar()) == '\n')
            printf("Please input a number\n");
        else if(input >= '0' && input <= '9') {
            do {
                num = num * 10 + input - '0';
            } while((input = getchar()) >= '0' && input <= '9');
            break;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```